# R - "find and replace" integers in a column with character labels

Tags: r, for-loop, apply

I have two data frames the first (DF1) is similar to this:

```
Ba    Ram    You    Sheep
30      1   33.2    120.9
27      3   22.1    121.2
22      4   39.1     99.1
11      1   20.0    101.6
 9      3    9.8    784.3
```

The second (DF2) contains titles for column "Ram":

```
V1    V2
 1   RED
 2   GRN
 3   YLW
 4   BLU
```

I need to replace the DF1$Ram with corresponding character strings of DF2$V2:

```
Ba    Ram    You    Sheep
30    RED   33.2    120.9
27    YLW   22.1    121.2
22    BLU   39.1     99.1
11    RED   20.0    101.6
 9    YLW    9.8    784.3
```

I can do this with a nested for loop, but it feels REALLY inefficient:

```
x <- c(1:nrows(DF1))
y <- c(1:4)
for (i in x) {
    for (j in y) {
        if (DF1$Ram[i] == x) {
            DF1$Ram[i] <- DF2$V2[y]
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do this more efficiently??!?! I know there is. I'm a noob.

Comment: You are looking into creating a factor with known levels and labels. Search first.

Comment: I seriously doubt your real data allows you to do this, but given your example it's as simple as; `DF1$Ram <- DF2$V2[ DF1$Ram ]`. You are right in that this is a basic question that you could solve by taking any number of introductory online tutorials/waklthroughs/guides.

Comment: @SimonO'Hanlon thanks - taking online tutorials/courses, but the examples of functions such as *apply are mind-blowingly simple, and don't incorporate objects other than simple vectors. Hopefully I can grasp enough of the language to be able to hack through things like this more effectively. I appreciate your patience.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `merge`

```
> result <- merge(df1, df2, by.x="Ram", by.y="V1")[,-1] # merging data.frames
> colnames(result)[4] <- "Ram"  # setting name
```

The following is just for getting the output in the order you showed us

```
> result[order(result$Ba, decreasing = TRUE), c("Ba", "Ram", "You", "Sheep")]
  Ba Ram  You Sheep
1 30 RED 33.2 120.9
3 27 YLW 22.1 121.2
5 22 BLU 39.1  99.1
2 11 RED 20.0 101.6
4  9 YLW  9.8 784.3
```

Answer (score 1):

Usually, when you encode some character strings with integers, you likely want factor. They offer some benefits you can read about in the fine manual.

```
df1 <- data.frame(V2 = c(3,3,2,3,1))
df2 <- data.frame(V1=1:4, V2=c('a','b','c','d'))

df1 <- within(df1, {
  f <- factor(df1$V2, levels=df2$V1, labels=df2$V2)
  aschar <- as.character(f)
  asnum <- as.numeric(f)
  })
```

Comment: Great - thanks for the advice. I've had trouble using factors once or twice when the # of observations aren't the same for each level; I'll have to check out the manual like you suggest.